# Setting CSS background-image where the image is a resource or WebResource in a .NET assembly

Tags: asp.net, css, background-image, embedded-resource

I am writing an ASP.NET server control that will live in its own assembly.  It's a refactoring of something already in the app, which uses CSS background images.

I don't want to require the user of the assembly to have to install a separate images folder, so -- if it's possible -- I'd like to store the images as resources in the server control's assembly.  But I'd still like to use CSS to set them as background images.  Unless I'm mistaken, CSS is my only option for setting background images.

Is this possible?  I've seen some markup in places that suggests it might be, notably [this](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jul/30/WebResource-access-in-ASPNET-MVC), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965378/background-image-of-a-css-loaded-as-an-embedded-resource), and [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1688474.aspx/1), but nothing sufficiently specific to CSS background images that I could be confident it would work: most articles that deal with this assume you are loading either script or CSS files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!  The answer is:  YES, you can do it!  And here's how:  [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1688474.aspx/1) and [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910442).