# I'm having trouble getting images to show up in a simple ASP.Net custom control

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls

I have experience with .ascx user controls but I wanted to get familiar with a custom control.

I created a simple control that includes embedded files (css, jQuery, and prettyBox files) along with an image.

All this control is doing is displaying an img link that will launch some inline content in the prettyBox window.

I had no trouble getting the inline content to launch but the img that I use as my link button isn't showing up and I'm not sure how to reference it correctly.

This is how I referenced all my embedded files. The img is in the root directory with all other files.

```
//Embedded Resources (reference files using project namespace)
[assembly: WebResource("CustomControlDemo.slide1.jpg", "image/jpg")]
[assembly: WebResource("CustomControlDemo.control.css", "text/css")]
[assembly: WebResource("CustomControlDemo.jquery-1.6.1.min.js", "text/javascript")]
[assembly: WebResource("CustomControlDemo.jquery.prettyPhoto.js", "text/javascript")]
[assembly: WebResource("CustomControlDemo.control.js", "text/javascript")]
```

Then I just emitted some simple html. The problem is that the img isn't found when I inspect it with the browser tools.

```
   protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.Write(@"<a href=""#inline"" rel=""prettyPhoto"">
                             <img src=""slide1.jpg"" alt="""" 
                                  width=""100px"" height=""67px""/>
                           </a>

                           <div id=""inline"" class=""hidden"">
                              <h1>This is inline content!</h1>
                           </div>");
        }
```

How exactly do you reference embedded img's in a custom control? I'd like to be able to put them in their own folder but for now I'd just like to be able get a single root img to show up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785173/setting-css-background-image-where-the-image-is-a-resource-or-webresource-in-a) (which was mine) asked about using embedded images with CSS, but I believe some of the links in the question and answer applied to image controls.

Here's an example:

```
<img src="<%= ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(Westwind.Web.Controls.AjaxMethodCallback),
                                        "Westwind.Web.Controls.Resources.calendar.gif") %>" />
```

Comment: Interesting. A link-only answer that links to another link-only answer.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev  Good point.  I've retrieved an example of how to do it from the link and added it.